# How can I downgrade my Nvidia drivers?

Tags: unity, drivers, nvidia, launcher

I just installed the Nvidia 304.51 and it works great, the problem is that now the Unity Launcher doesn't auto-hide. I found [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1057000) so it seems there isn't a way to fix it. One way to get auto-hide again it would be to downgrade to the last version of the Nvidia drivers (so it shows in the bug report comments), the thing is that I didn't install the drivers using PPA but using [this method](http://podzemski.com/2012/10/20/ubuntu-12-10-nvidia-drivers/).

Any ideas on how I can downgrade my Nvidia drivers to "fix" this?

Comment: Have you checked `system settings > appearance > behavior`? There Auto hide option must be checked.

Answer (score 0):

To downgrade a package you can use the command

```
sudo dpkg -i <packagenamehere>
```

Did the auto hide option in the appearance settings just get unchecked?